# Cannot access localhost with proxy enabled

Tags: debian, proxy, apache-http-server, lubuntu

My office is a Windows environment, but I have just set up a linux (lubuntu 12.10) machine for me to develop on since I cannot access the command line in Windows.

I have set up the LAMP stack on the machine (which I've done numerous times before without fail), but I cannot access `localhost`, I get a connection refused error.

In order to use the internet on the machine I've had to add our proxy details to `/etc/environment` - the internet works fine.

If I get rid of the proxy settings, I can then access `localhost`, but that of course means I cannot get on the internet.

So how do I access localhost with a proxy enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried it, but a quick google suggests that you can set

```
no_proxy='127.0.0.1,localhost'
```

Comment: Thanks, I just solved this myself and was about to post an answer - you beat me to it.